# Rails - having difficulty with group, user, owner, member associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I've looked everywhere and have been unable to find exactly what I'm looking for. I have an idea of what I need, but am unable to put 2 and 2 together.

- I need to allow users to create groups and allow other users to join the     groups.
- Any user can create a group.
- Any user can send a request to join another group.
- A user can CREATE only ONE group, but can BELONG to MANY groups.
- The creator of the group is the owner of the group.
- All of the members and the owner are regular users with no special permissions.
- The group creator/owner can add/remove other group members.

This code isn't proper, but this is the idea:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :owner, :class_name => "user"
 has_many :members, :class_name => "user"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :groups
 has_one :group, :class_name "user"
end
```

I believe I need a has_many :through association, but am unsure about how to implement it. How do I build my models/controllers/migrations in order to represent the association within the parameters above?

Comment: please ask a specific question.

Comment: Edited for specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest as well using a join table as follows:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owned_group, foreign_key: "owner_id", class_name: "Group"
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
  has_many :memberships
end
```

Migrations are as follows:

```
class CreateMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :memberships do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :group

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.references :owner

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

[image: schema design]

Comment: Does the owner_id come from a separate Owner model? How is the owner_id and owner class enforced in the migration?

Comment: I don't know, ```has_one :group``` and ```has_many :groups``` on the same model, that could be confusing.

Comment: Correct. We could change :group to :owned_group adding class_name option... I'll edit.

Comment: I really appreciate how thorough the answer is. How are you able to use has_one and has_many within the same model in that manner? I'm just fuzzy in the details of how those two associations mesh so easily.

Comment: The two associations are completely separate, and are not leveraging the same tables/keys. I guess a little schema design picture would help... I'll try to make a quick one, and attach.

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been extremely helpful! Selected your answer for being so thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Rails applications use `has_many through:` instead of HABTM.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups

end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one  :owner, through: :user_groups, source: :user
  has_many :members, through: :user_groups, source: :user

end

class UserGroups < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :owner, uniqueness: true
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Adding `source` on `has_many` and `has_one` allows you to write `Group.find(id).members` and `Group.find(id).owner`. Validate the uniqueness of a group owner on the join.

Comment: Would there need to be any special conditions within my controllers? What would the migration files for each look like?

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

The main types you could use in this case and depend on your requirements are

```
has_many :groups, through: join_table
```

where the join table would reference both the user and the group by having user_id and group_id. This allows you to have additional information related to the group membership, maybe you want a join date or a membership id or something like that.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
```

which is implemented in a similar fashion but bypassess the join model and would simply give you a list of groups/users on either side of the relationship

Polymorphic relationships wouldn't really come into play unless you were planning on having maybe different types of memberships, maybe groups, or organizations or something that would require similar, but separate database tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm fairly certain that the has_many :through is what I need. So how would I go about setting a single owner per group? That seems to be my greatest difficulty. I can pretty easily create a group that has many members, but creating a group that has many members AND has one owner who controls it is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: so from the perspective of the group... you want 2 things. An owner, and members which are both made up of User models.

so on the Group model you would want 


`has_one :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'`
`has_many :members, through: :join_table`


They can both reference the same model type, they just need a different name/relationship to point to.

Comment: That is exactly what I need.